# how to control youtube videos with chrome extention?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, youtube, youtube-api

i want to write a chrome extention,which can control the video which i am seeing it in youtube.com,for example stop,play and pause it with a 'browser-action' buttons.
i tried alot to do it with javascript,as an example i wrote a code like this;

```
var btn=document.getelementbyid('the button id');
var video=document.getelementbyid('video');    //current video on youtube which is  playing 
btn.addeventlistener('click',function(){

  video.stop()
   })
```

i always get this error=>video.stop() is not a function...
my question is why i am getting this error?
my second  question is can i wrap the video element with an iframe tag (not by loading the video into another page,just in youtube.com) and control it right there?

Answer (score 1):

Try this in the console while on a video page:

`document.getElementById('movie_player').pauseVideo()`

or

`document.getElementById('movie_player').playVideo()`

This should work.

Please note that getElementById is not the same as getelementbyid in Javascript! Also it's addEventListener, not addeventlistener. Function and variable names are generally in camelCase in Javascript.

Comment: i found the solution...i must use video[0].play() instead of video.play.... it took me hourse for that